# excel, viewing which "data connections have been disabled"

Tags: excel, security, connection, warnings

I have an excel project that currently has "data connections" disabled. How can I see what that data connection is, such as destination IP address within excel, without loading a packet analyzer like Wireshark (and enabling the connection).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Excel 2007 and above, click 'Data' -> 'Connections' to show a list, and click 'Properties' to look at the connection string etc.

Comment: Not seeing "Connections" in Excel 2011 (OSX)